# C# Logfile is always blank when redirecting output of Process that runs Shell Commands

Tags: c#, process, cmd, redirectstandardoutput

I've the below code where I use DevCon.exe to capture something and write it in a file. I parse this file for a need.

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C devcon.exe find = port *monitor* >> monitor_Details.txt";
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();

StreamReader sr = p.StandardOutput;
string log = sr.ReadToEnd();
StreamWriter sw = p.StandardInput;
sw.WriteLine("hi.txt");
p.Close();
```

Here, I see the txt file being blank all the time. Nothing is written into the text file.
Is there anything wrong? I also checked variable log which gets assigned to

> sr.ReadToEnd()

even then log is always blank.

Pl help why shell commands are not getting executed:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
port *monitor* >> monitor_Details.txt
```

CMD shell output redirection within a Process object does not work the way it works in your console shell. The `">>"` and `"|"` are non-functional within a Process context.

You will need to run `devcon.exe` directly within Process object instead of wrapping under CMD.EXE. Then capture your output from buffer of the Process object and save it into the txt file if you want the log.  Just pass your necessary argument as "`find = port *monitor*`" as you are doing in your example.

MSDN has detailed example and best practices on output buffer capturing. [Read here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx). and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx).

Comment: when I use Devcon.exe directly, it gives me error saying "the requested operation requires elevation" - as you can see I've p.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";

Comment: If you are in debug mode in VS then start VS by right clicking and selecting "run as admin". If running the app directly then run the as admin.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar program but redirecting output to a panel of my application.

i would add

```
            P.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            P.OutputDataReceived += proc_OutputDataReceived;
            P.ErrorDataReceived  += proc_ErrorDataReceived;

            P.Start();

            P.BeginOutputReadLine();
            P.BeginErrorReadLine();
```

this means you read the data from the buffer as it comes in and can choose to redirect it to a file

```
    void proc_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        //e.Data contains the console output. You can redirect it where ever you like
    }
```

Hope it helps